# Angularjs Autocomplete Keyboard Navigation

Tags: angularjs, accessibility

I'm trying to implement keyboard navigation for autocomplete.

Here is a partial implemention of  autocomplete.

I like to have up & down  arrow work on  anchor tag including subheader.

If Enter key is pressed while on navigation it should  do same as anchor click

http://plnkr.co/edit/wXStq02jzO4gfj1F8dKG?p=preview

What is the elegant and simple way to do this.

```
 (function(angular) {
  'use strict';
     var myApp = angular.module('spicyApp1', []);

     myApp.controller('SpicyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.searchOneArr = [{
        name: 'FirstName1 LastName1',
        title: 'Title1',
        desc : 'Desc1'
     },{
       name: 'FirstName2 LastName2',
       title: 'Title2',
       desc : 'Desc2'
     }];

     $scope.searchTwoArr = [{
       title : 'google'
     },{
       title : 'yahoo'
     },{
       title : 'msn'
     },{
       title : 'facebook'
     }];
   }]);
  })(window.angular);
```

Comment: Updated demo with key navigation which highlights href. Still more to go.

Comment: Updated the demo, highlighting using `activeindex` variable.
mouseover and setting index also done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have currently done it doesn't go well with what's recommended, namely you shouldn't mix dom operations with controllers.  But assuming this is the way you want to do it then in your controller add

```
$element.bind('keydown', function(e){
  if (e.keyCode !== 13) return;
  var $item = $element.find('.active');
  var link = $item.attr('href');
  window.open(link, '_blank');
})
```

Check [here for example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HdeGTjdrCzCWpLgJma7U?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the example,  this actually solves my problem, do you have better suggestion , i will change my implementation accordingly.

Comment: I would recommend using directives for the job.  As for how you implement it is up to you.  You should avoid the element variable in a controller because the way you have done it is more like a jquery implementation rather than an angular one, nevertheless it gets the job done.  Dont worry, this is all part of the infamous angular learning curve. As your application grows, you will naturally learn the angular way.  But for now I wouldn't be too fussed about implementing it a different way as that would pretty much mean a whole rewrite.

Comment: I will explore more on this, meanwhile if you know any clean implementation  please do share.

I have also updated my plnk  based on your inputs.

Comment: I don't know a clean implementation of what you are doing.  What I'm talking about is angular in general, read this style guide to get you started - https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide   The purpose of having this style is for maintainability, testability and readability which is what angular is built for.  Was there anything else you needed for this task? Otherwise, I believe it's solved?